# Ubuntu 22.04 vm bridge to wifi so that vms get ip address via dhcp

Tags: networking, wireless, virtualization, dhcp, network-bridge

### Preamble

I've tried following assorted tutorials. None are specific to Ubuntu 22.04. Every one I've tried so far end up with me having to reinstall to get wifi working. Some assume the machine has a static IP connected via wired ethernet.

So I'm asking about Ubuntu 22.04 (i.e. an answer that works for Debian 9, or that is for a fixed IP on a wired ethernet, is not what I'm asking about as I don't know how to adapt things to my setup — previous attempts messed up the network config), and with the network connection being via wifi with dhcp from the router.*

## The question

Starting from a stock install of 22.04, what do I need to do so that a vm can get its own IP from the router via dhcp and be visible to other machines on the network?

(VirtualBox can bridge vms to the wifi, so it seems possible.)

(*At present I'm having most success running the VMs with VirtualBox on my Windows box. Some of my Linux machines fail to start VirtualBox VMs and I can't figure out why, when virt-manager has no problem starting the same iso images.*)

Comment: Unless you are specifically telling the VM that the network adapter is a wireless device, VirtualBox will present it to the VM as a wired network connection. This is fine. Set the adapter to “Bridged” and the promiscuous mode (under “Advanced”) to Allow All.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate with virt-manager what VirtualBox does with its Bridged mode.